# c# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am facing a problem with that description:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
> Additional information: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

The problem shows up when i call my `Getall` method

`var gruppi = GroupHelper.GetAll().OrderBy(a => a.Order);`

GetAll Method:

```
public new static ICollection<Group> GetAll()
    {
        using (var provider = new GroupProvider())
        {
          provider.QAll().Include
          (a => a.RoleGroup.Select(c => c.Role)).
          Include(a=>a.GroupLanguage.Select(b=>b.Language).
          Where(c=>c.LanguageName=="ENG")).ToList();               
        }
    }
```

The properties of `GroupLanguage` and `RoleGroup` are the following:

```
public class GroupLanguage
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid LanguageID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LanguageID")]
    public Language Language { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GroupID")]
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class RoleGroup
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

Any Idea why is this happening ?

Comment: Adding a try-catch block will likely help you figure out steps to solve this problem.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @confusedandamused I tried to split the query but with no success, i get the same exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter in an `Include`, you need to make reference to a navigation property. Remove the `Where` call inside:

```
public new static ICollection<Group> GetAll()
{
    using (var provider = new GroupProvider())
    {
      provider.QAll().Include(a => a.RoleGroup.Select(c => c.Role))
                     .Include(a=>a.GroupLanguage.Select(b=>b.Language)).ToList();               
    }
}
```

If you need to load only `GroupLanguage` with `LanguageName=="ENG"`, then you should project your query, but you're going to loose your entity type because Linq to entities only support project queries into an anonymous object or a [DTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5),eg:

```
public new static ICollection<GroupDTO> GetAll()
{
    using (var provider = new GroupProvider())
    {
      provider.QAll().Include(a => a.RoleGroup.Select(c => c.Role))
                     .Include(a=>a.GroupLanguage.Select(b=>b.Language))
                     .Select(a=>new GroupDTO{GroupName=a.Name, 
                                             Language=a.GroupLanguage.Select(b=>b.Language)
                                                                     .Where(c=>c.LanguageName=="ENG")})
                     .ToList();               
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm ok i will try it...But what GroupDTO suppose to be ? i am a bit new at in entity framework

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that, it's a custom class that you define with the properties you only need